# My low beam only works when I take the high beam fuse out

Tags: electrical, honda, accord, headlight

I have a 2008 Honda Accord. The right low beam stopped working so I took the right **high beam** fuse out and the right low beam started working again but when I put the high beam fuse back and turned the lights on the right low beam stopped working again. So I took the high beam fuse out again – now my both low beams are working fine. But the right high beam is not working..

In short,  my right low beam only works when I take the right high beam fuse out. Any solution? Both fuses seems fine.

Comment: Off hand it sounds like you might have a ground problem.

Comment: Do you have access to a volt meter?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a grounding problem or wires that melted together and are not shorted. I think you will need your wiring schematics and possibly a tone generator to find where the short is.

revisiting this I think there may be some crossed circuits as in melted wires before your fuse box. This would mean the electricity takes the path of least resistance aka the high beam (I am assuming when you headlights are on you have one low and one high beam going and pulling the fuse switches to only low) pulling the fuse breaks this and allows the electricity to flow through the low beam. This is still just speculation though.

If I can get more info I might be able to come up with a more helpfuyl answer.

- if the low beams only are on, which headlights are lit? low beams? high beams? one of each? high and low beams at the same time? some other combination?
- if you switch to high beams, which headlights are lit? low beams? high beams? one of each? high and low beams at the same time? some other combination?
- if the low beams only are on, with the fuse removed, which headlights are lit? low beams? high beams? one of each? high and low beams at the same time? some other combination?
- if you switch to high beams, with the fuse removed, which headlights are lit? low beams? high beams? one of each? high and low beams at the same time? some other combination?

Answer (score 1):

One other thing that I'd suggest is that you remove the high beam bulb on the right hand side. If you don't have a meter you could swap the bulb for the one on the left side and see if the problem goes with the bulb.

The bulb is the most fragile component in the system and if this is a new problem is seems possible that the cause could be something in the bulb. Swapping out for a known good one would be a easy way to test out that possibility.